# What's the right way to write this query in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

```
Names
- id (int)
- name (string)
```

and

```
Relationships
- id1 (int)
- id2 (int)
```

I want to query a list of all relationships that have certain id1, and I want to include the names from Names in the resulting query.

So, the result would have four columns

- id1
- id2
- name_for_id1
- name_for_id2

Is this possible? I know I can do an inner join to include one of the names, but I am not sure how to include both names.

For one name I would do something like:

```
select Relationships.id1, Relationships.id2, Names.name from Relationships
inner join Names
on Names.id1 = Relationships.id1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can join a table twice.

```
SELECT
   r.id1,
   r.id2,
   n1.name,
   n2.name
FROM Relationships r
INNER JOIN Names n1 ON r.id1 = n1.id
INNER JOIN Names n2 ON r.id2 = n2.id
```

Comment: I wondered if this was the right solution! I was worried it would return two rows, one for id1 and one for id2. I'll have a go at it later.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do a second join to `Names`.  You can use table aliases to specify which join is which.

```
select r.id1, r.id2, n1.name, n2.name
from Relationships r
inner join Names n1
    on n1.id = r.id1
inner join Names n2
    on n2.id = r.id2
```

Comment: Can you explain your query with a dry run on it? it is a bit confusing!

Comment: @CodeLover This says that you pull all rows from `Relationships`, using the name `r` to keep things short.  For each row in `r` you join to `Names` where `id1` matches `id`, calling this `n1`.  You then, again, join `r` and `Names`, this time matching against `id2`, calling these matching rows `n2`.  You alias `Names` as `n1` and `n2` because there would otherwise be no way to distinguish which `name` is which - this way `n1.name` and `n2.name` unambiguously reference the name that matches `id1` and `id2`, respectively.